# Create table without dataset in a rdlc report.

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, rdlc

I'm developing a rdlc report in VS2010 and I need to add a table in the report, but this table has fixed text and doesn't need a datasource. But the report is giving an error because the table isn't related to a datasource. So my question is How do I create table in an rdlc that doesn't need a datsource?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

By definition a table needs an associated DataSet.

If you only have one DataSet in a report it can use that by default, otherwise one will need to be specified.

If you don't want to associate the table with a DataSet, you could use one or more independent textboxes placed together to get the same results.

You can embed these textboxes in a Rectangle to keep them together when rendering the report.

Comment: You can embed these textboxes in a Rectangle to keep them together when rendering the report... Sorry, but this approach is so messy it is no even funny. It presents all sorts of layout problems.

Comment: @tom33pr Sorry to say that, but RDLC was never fun nor funny. :-(

Answer (score 2):

If you have fixed values you do not need a Table. Rather, try putting **parameters**.

In any case, I still suggest you build a `DataSet` to create a `DataTable`. Programmatically filling your `DataTable` is **flexible** and it would still meet your needs.

For example, your `DataTable` can contain your fixed values and you can simply attach your `DataTable` to the report's **Datasource**. I believe this is your easiest solution.

Comment: @SouhaiebBesbes I have many questions/answers on my profile for reports and such. Feel free to look! 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18787907/how-to-add-two-datatables-to-a-tablix-using-reportviewer-design