# How to Add Two DataTables to a Tablix Using ReportViewer Design

Tags: vb.net, datatable, reportviewer

I am trying to add two DataTables to a Table (tablix) in my report using ReportViewer.

**DataTables**

- dtPrograms *(Name, Description)*
- dtImprovements *(Improvement)*

I'll have a list of programs and a list of improvements for each program.

Here's an example of what I'm looking for:

[image: ReportViewer goal: Programs with their improvements]

I'm not sure how to design my ReportViewer. Is using a Table (tablix) a good method or are there easier methods of doing so? Perhaps using a Matrix? How would you go about designing a report that contains two DataTables?

Comment: create a dataset with a join query then use that as the data source for your tablix

Comment: @peterG The way a tablix works is it will add the name, description and improvement every time it has an improvement. Ideally, I would need to create a tablix in a tablix ... But I can't use two datatables in that case.

Comment: Create the dataset with a join query against both tables. This will give you rows with programname, description, improvement in each row.
Then use the grouping features of the tablix to create the layout as per your sample.

Comment: Alternatively if you are using a List(of Object) as your datasource, as in your other comment, then again you can simply use the Grouping features of the tablix to get your desired layout.

Comment: @peterG Thank you, your tips helped me figure it out. I'll find another way to reward you for the help ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Detailed Solution

I manually created a DataSet (`ds`), a DataTable (`dtTest`) and manually populated it with information. For example:

```
ds.dtTest.Rows.Add("Test1", "Description 1", "Improvement 1 for Test1")
ds.dtTest.Rows.Add("Test1", "Description 1", "Improvement 2 for Test1")
ds.dtTest.Rows.Add("Test1", "Description 1", "Improvement 3 for Test1")
ds.dtTest.Rows.Add("Test1", "Description 1", "Improvement 4 for Test1")
ds.dtTest.Rows.Add("Test2", "Description 2", "Improvement 1 for Test2")
ds.dtTest.Rows.Add("Test2", "Description 2", "Improvement 2 for Test2")
ds.dtTest.Rows.Add("Test3", "Description 3", "Improvement 1 for Test3")
ds.dtTest.Rows.Add("Test3", "Description 3", "Improvement 2 for Test3")
ds.dtTest.Rows.Add("Test3", "Description 3", "Improvement 3 for Test3")
ds.dtTest.Rows.Add("Test3", "Description 3", "Improvement 4 for Test3")
ds.dtTest.Rows.Add("Test4", "Description 4", "Improvement 1 for Test4")
```

---

### 1. Add the Tablix to the Report

[image: New Tablix]

---

### 2. Remove all but 1 column. Keep the column that will be repeated

In my case, I add the Improvement column here

[image: Add Improvement column]

---

### 3. Add Parent Group to the Improvement Column

I right click on the Improvement cell and Add Group > Parent Group (Under Row Groups)

[image: Add Row Group]

---

### 4. Group By Name

[image: Group By Name]

---

### 5. Add a child group to your name column

This is where I add my description

[image: Add Child Group to Name Column]

---

### 6. Add Description

[image: Add Description]

### 7. Remove Headers

[image: Remove headers]

---

### Result

Here is the design:

[image: Design]

Here is the final result:
[image: Result]

Comment: Awesome explanation dude. Awesome.

Answer (score 2):

In the Report Designer, Reports Items may have one and only one DataSet connected to it. So say your Tablix named "Tablix1" may only have one DataSet connected to it. However, if you have data from 2 Database Tables that you want to have displayed in one tablix, say "Tablix1" all you have to do it create a DataSet(.xsd) file, In there create a TableAdapter and use a query to join the two desired tables you want into one DataSet Object, then give the Report Designer that DataSet and connect "Tablix1" to it. This will allow for you to have (essentially) 2 DataSets for 1 Table.

The difference between Matrices and Tables are minuscule. If I'm not mistaken, matrices are for the case where you want Column & Row Headers and Tables are for the general column headers only. However, Tables & Matrices are both a "Tablix" when it comes to .rdlc reports. So there's nothing majorly different between the two, one is just simply easier to do row headers on.

Comment: How would I get a List(Of Object) in a DataSet using a TableAdapter ... The List(Of Object) is what enables me to have a list of improvements

Comment: You can just give the Report the whole DataSet, Create a ReportDataSource object using the DataTable retrieved from your Query, then feed that to the Report (This is how you would do it if your ReportViewer is in Local Mode, as opposed to Remote Processing Mode).

Comment: Yes that's what I ended up doing. Just needed to group it by name and description. Thanks for the help though