# RDLC create table without Dataset

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reporting-services, rdlc

I have refereed this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16969839/create-table-without-dataset-in-a-rdlc-report) which is same like this but it is not active and doesn't include solution.

I have a MVC application in which i can generate blank report in pdf format.I have a Report_Name.rdlc report file and added a Table just to see how it looks when i generate report. I **don't** have any data set so i cancelled option asking for dataset.

Now it gives me error :

> Error 3   The tablix ‘Tablix8’ is in the report body but the report has no dataset.  Data regions are not allowed in reports without datasets.

I don't want any dataset to bind with my table. i just want to make a table in rdlc report & run my mvc application to see how it looks.

any suggestion ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to assign a dataset to a tablix, there is no way around it. Just create a dummy dataset that only returns one field with no data; maybe the SQL could be `SELECT GETDATE() AS blah`  (if you are using SQL Server). Set the dummy dataset as the dataset for the tablix, and do what you need to with it.